# I am also getting this error on ROS realsense D435 camera. The code I wrote "roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rgbd.launch"

Tags: python, ubuntu, intel, ros, realsense

Error message:

```
opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib//librealsense2_camera.so: undefined symbol: _ZN20ddynamic_reconfigure19DDynamicReconfigureC1ERKN3ros10NodeHandleE
[camera/realsense2_camera_manager-2] process has died [pid 13033, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=realsense2_camera_manager __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/bb60da40-105c-11ec-bdf8-27733b72faf1/camera-realsense2_camera_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/bb60da40-105c-11ec-bdf8-27733b72faf1/camera-realsense2_camera_manager-2*.log
[camera/realsense2_camera-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/bb60da40-105c-11ec-bdf8-27733b72faf1/camera-realsense2_camera-3*.log
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. it was caused by having `ddynamic_reconfigure repo` inside src/ and already installed `ddynamic_reconfigure` using apt

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic ros-melodic-ddynamic-reconfigure.
```

Fixed by removing `src/ddynamic_reconfigure/` and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different issues that could cause this problem. First, this can be caused by having more than one installation of `dynamic_reconfigure` on your system. You should also make sure you're `CMakeLists.txt` includes `image_geometry` in its call to `find_package`.

Comment: I looked at my dynamic_reconfigure files and it shows 1. I also get an error when I do catkin_make

Comment: You should include the error in your post then. I imagine that's quite relevant.

Comment: opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib//librealsense2_camera.so: undefined symbol: _ZN20ddynamic_reconfigure19DDynamicReconfigureC1ERKN3ros10NodeHandleE
[camera/realsense2_camera_manager-2] process has died [pid 13033, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=realsense2_camera_manager __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/bb60da40-105c-11ec-bdf8-27733b72faf1/camera-realsense2_camera_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/bb60da40-105c-11ec-bdf8-27733b72faf1/camera-realsense2_camera_manager-2*.log